# Editing XML files with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, json, xml, soap

So as you can see, we have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <GetECConfigResponse xmlns="urn:ecs.wsapi.broadon.com">
            <Version>2.0</Version>
            <DeviceId>4498122730</DeviceId>
            <MessageId>ECDK-4498122730-39653600512638909</MessageId>
            <TimeStamp>1599408189821</TimeStamp>
            <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
            <ServiceStandbyMode>false</ServiceStandbyMode>
            <ContentPrefixURL>http://example.com</ContentPrefixURL>
            <UncachedContentPrefixURL>http://example.com</UncachedContentPrefixURL>
            <SystemContentPrefixURL>http://example.com</SystemContentPrefixURL>
            <SystemUncachedContentPrefixURL>http://example.com</SystemUncachedContentPrefixURL>
            <EcsURL>http://example.com</EcsURL>
            <IasURL>http://example.com</IasURL>
            <CasURL>http://example.com</CasURL>
            <NusURL>http://example.com</NusURL>
        </GetECConfigResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I do this so I can edit stuff inside the xml depending on the user's POST body but I have to edit the stuff I want, and turn it into a XML back again and send it as a response, since it's not possible with Node.JS to edit the XML directly without converting to JS or JSON

```
const xmlParser = require("xml2json");
var json2xml = require("json2xml");

// Current time in epoch
function currentEpoch() {
    const now = Date.now()
        return now
}
// Read the XML file
fs.readFile("./ecs/ecommercesoap/getecconfigresponse.xml", function (err, data) {
    // Convert the XML to JSON
    const xmlObj = xmlParser.toJson(data, {
        object: true
    })
        // Get the user's body details
        var deviceId = req.body["DeviceId"]
        // Change XML index depending on the user
        xmlObj["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"]["GetECConfigResponse"]["DeviceId"] = deviceId
        xmlObj["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"]["GetECConfigResponse"]["TimeStamp"] = currentEpoch().toString()
```

This is where it converts xmlObj back to xml again

```
// Convert the JSON to XML and finalize it
    const finalXml = xmlParser.toXml(xmlObj)
    
// Set the response's type as application/xml
    res.type('application/xml');
    
// Sending the completely edited XML back to the user
    res.send(finalXml)
```

And as you can see, the output changes when the converting happens. The XML below is after it's edited and parsed back into XML from JSON. If you noticed, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is also deleted, which shouldn't be.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <GetECConfigResponse xmlns="urn:ecs.wsapi.broadon.com" Version="2.0" DeviceId="4498122730" MessageId="ECDK-4498122730-39653600512638909" TimeStamp="1599505063565" ErrorCode="0" ServiceStandbyMode="false" ContentPrefixURL="http://example.com" UncachedContentPrefixURL="http://example.com" SystemContentPrefixURL="http://example.com" SystemUncachedContentPrefixURL="http://example.com" EcsURL="http://example.com" IasURL="http://example.com" CasURL="http://example.com" NusURL="http://example.com"/>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So I wonder what can I do to fix this, the tags start and end with `<>` in the original while edited one doesn't even have it. Long story short, bunch of stuff got changed. I also tried `xml2js` instead of `xml2json` but the output is still the same. I just want my output exactly same as the original file, but with my stuff changed.

Comment: Why don't you use something like `soap` package?

Comment: I am okay with what I use right now and that's not the case either.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing any good reason for converting the XML to JSON and back again. Why don't you simply do the transformation in XSLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our project we have to deal with manually modifiying soap/xml in NodeJS as well - we've recently switched to [fast-xml-parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser) and are really happy with it. I took your sample input and using the following code:

```
const xmlToJsonParser = require('fast-xml-parser');
const options = {
    ignoreAttributes: false,
    ignoreNameSpace: false,
    parseNodeValue: true,
    parseAttributeValue: true,
    trimValues: true,
};
// xmlData refers to the xml-string 
const tObj = xmlToJsonParser.getTraversalObj(xmlData, options);
const jsonObj = xmlToJsonParser.convertToJson(tObj, options);
// modify json
jsonObj["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"]["GetECConfigResponse"].DeviceId = 123456;

const JsonToXmlParser = require("fast-xml-parser").j2xParser;
const parser = new JsonToXmlParser({format: true, ignoreAttributes: false});
const xml = parser.parse(jsonObj);
console.log(xml);
```

it produces:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <GetECConfigResponse xmlns="urn:ecs.wsapi.broadon.com">
      <Version>2</Version>
      <DeviceId>123456</DeviceId>
      <MessageId>ECDK-4498122730-39653600512638909</MessageId>
      <TimeStamp>1599408189821</TimeStamp>
      <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
      <ServiceStandbyMode>false</ServiceStandbyMode>
      <ContentPrefixURL>http://example.com</ContentPrefixURL>
      <UncachedContentPrefixURL>http://example.com</UncachedContentPrefixURL>
      <SystemContentPrefixURL>http://example.com</SystemContentPrefixURL>
      <SystemUncachedContentPrefixURL>http://example.com</SystemUncachedContentPrefixURL>
      <EcsURL>http://example.com</EcsURL>
      <IasURL>http://example.com</IasURL>
      <CasURL>http://example.com</CasURL>
      <NusURL>http://example.com</NusURL>
    </GetECConfigResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

All that's left is to prepend the xml-header, as they've decided to exclude this feature from the parser (https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/issues/184).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I'd like to know how can I read the xml file because when I tried it with my fs code in the question, I got a weird error `xmlData = xmlData.replace(/(\r\n)|\n/, " "); TypeError: xmlData.replace is not a function`

Comment: Have you checked `err` in the callback? You need to make sure it's not defined before continuing.

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(xmlData)` after reading the file, please?

Comment: Thank you for solving the issue! You're the best.